# PWA - Register service worker in dev mode

Tags: create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I would like to try PWA with create react app version 4.0, i did manage to generate new project as below

`npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript`

When i try to run npm start i don't see any service-worker.js registered in chrome browser but if i build and serve then it works fine. I would like to register service-worker.js in dev mode, so i followed this article [Easy Workbox Integration with create-react-app](https://kelvinmwinuka.com/easy-workbox-integration-with-create-react-app/)  I have removed the production environment check in serviceWorkerRegistration.ts but no luck.

**serviceWorkerRegistration.ts**

`if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator)`

Please advise ?

Answer (score 0):

The service worker is only enabled in the production environment, e.g. the output of npm run build. It's recommended that you do not enable an offline-first service worker in a development environment, as it can lead to frustration when previously cached assets are used and do not include the latest changes you've made locally.

from here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/